# Having issue building TestG maven project in Jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have an issue with building TestNG based Maven project via Jenkins. The issue is that if I have less number of test to run (up to 30) everything runs fine, but as soon as I increase the number, the build fails consistently. The problem I see is that, tests doesn't start until all the browser instance are open (eg, browser opens 30 windows first then start execution for suite of 30 tests) and when the test gets complete(not entire test suite), the browser window doesn't close (even after adding driver.quit() method) and it remains open till the TestSuite run is complete.

Below is snippet of my code.

Main Java class:

```
public class AccountManagement {
    public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    public WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    public void login(String uid, String pass) throws Throwable {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(URL);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(uid);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(pass);
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();

        <!-- REST OF THE CODE-->
    }
}
```

Sample test class:

```
public class TC_AC408 extends AccountManagement {

    @Test(retryAnalyzer=Retry.class)
    public void accountActionLinks() {
        login("auto.admin@test.com", "test@123");
        <!-- REST OF THE CODE-->
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void end() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Here is my testng.xml:

```
<suite name="Smoke Test" preserve-order="true" thread-count="1" verbose="1" parallel="false">
    <test name="Accounts">
        <classes>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC408"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC409"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC410"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC411"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC412"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC413"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC414"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC416"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Organization">
        <classes>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC470"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC474"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC475"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC477"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC478"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Project Management">
        <classes>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC186"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC191"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC193"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC194"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC195"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC196"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC200"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC785"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC786"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC788"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC790"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Registration">
        <classes>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC381"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC385"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC387"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC398"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC386"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC388"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Product">
        <classes>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC482"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC483"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC486"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC487"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC489"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC491"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC492"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC1777"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC1823"></class>
            <class name="SmokeTests.TC_AC1949"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"/>
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
        <listener class-name="SmokeTests.RetryListener"/>
    </listeners>
</suite>
```

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--suppress ALL -->
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 h
ttp://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project_selenium_mvn</groupId>
    <artifactId>project_selenium_mvn</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Adding Selenium dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.48.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.40</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And below is the error I am getting:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) on project acutiy_selenium_mvn: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Cannot instantiate class SmokeTests.TC_AC193
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:37)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:372)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:284)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:109)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:181)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\AutomatedTest\project_selenium_mvn\pom.xml to project_selenium_mvn/project_selenium_mvn/1.0-SNAPSHOT/project_selenium_mvn-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:402)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:228)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:198)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:147)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:525)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:156)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:110)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1235)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1222)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1074)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:999)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:282)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:83)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:114)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:286)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:240)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:28)
[ERROR] ... 22 more
[ERROR] Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7079; process output follows:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'
[ERROR] System info: host: 'WIN-O8VQ2P3P2GD', ip: '172.31.62.242', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
[ERROR] Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:135)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
[ERROR] at Automation.ProjectManagementPage.<init>(ProjectManagementPage.java:17)
[ERROR] at SmokeTests.TC_AC193.<init>(TC_AC193.java:15)
[ERROR] ... 27 more
[ERROR] Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7079 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:123)
[ERROR] ... 35 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: Is there any changes you have made to configuration ? Can you try to update project from Maven or convert the project to Maven. 
Converting to maven worked for my test project.

right click on project->Configure->Convert it to Maven

Comment: @Abhinav : Yes I did update the project, there is no issue with that, even created new from scratch just to make sure no unwanted code/file or dependencies are creating issues. The problem I see is when I increase the number of tests to be run.

Comment: The error is caused by 
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7079; process output follows:

Can you please check, where are you opening your browser ?

Comment: @Abhinav : I am not able to track the same, but the issue is reproducible in all the machine I tried.

Comment: Try checking the test cases that webdriver instance is being properly quit or being properly initialized. Try using different selenium version.

Comment: @Abhinav: Tried but that too didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating driver instance whenever for every class inside a test and quitting driver only once per test.Instead of instantiating WebDriver directly in class do it in @BeforeTest. It will ensure only one driver is created per test.

Your class whould look like below after upation.

```
public class AccountManagement {
public WebDriver driver;
public WebDriverWait wait;
@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest(){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
}
public void login(String uid, String pass) throws Throwable {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(URL);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(uid);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(pass);
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();

    <!-- REST OF THE CODE-->
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes, bro that was 1 part of issue which I fixed recently, other part was that it didn't close the browser instance as soon as test completed. I fixed it by adding driver.close() at the end of the main method.